# Prevent back button from exiting cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been struggling with this issue where in my cordova app, the back button will exit the app no matter what. I have tried all the solutions I've come across online but haven't had any success.

All the solutions I've tried (example below) have produced the same result.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

The code inside my callback executes without issue, but after it executes, it exits the app. I can prevent the exit by including a `ReferenceError` in my function, for example

```
console.log(undefinedVar);
```

But this obviously doesn't seem like best practice.

The other solutions I've tried include using `event.preventDefault()` from the callback and ionic's `registerBackButtonAction` function.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code works for me - document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);function onBackButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");
}

function onConfirm(button) {
    if (button == 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}

Comment: U can try my code I have Tried and it worked for me..It help in preventing from going back into other ba previous page,...Disabling the Back Button key in Android for Cordova As well as Phone Gap....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stopping Back Button</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="tex`enter code here`t/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function getTitle() {
            document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = "DEMO: " + document.title;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        getTitle();
    }
    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        alert('Back Button Disabled');
        console.log('Back Button Disabled');
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">&larr; Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="ct" onclick="location.reload();"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: U can try this one I have Tried and it worked for me..Thanks